# Why does nginx remove a / in the URL?

Tags: nginx

We use nginx as proxy for our play framework 1.2.7 server. Some of the routes in play framework use a <.*> wildcard, the one in question here looks like

```
GET     /media/{bucket}/{id}/inline/{<.*>config}    MediaCtl.getMediaInlineImgIx
```

The config can contain a http server and for some reason nginx strips away one of the / in http:// . For example:

```
13:07:59,299 INFO  [play] ~ Anonymous Guest ~ MediaCtl.getImgIx(): config {"w":100,"h":65,"origin":"http:/localhost:8080","fit":"max"}
```

when using nginx via localhost:8080. When calling localhost:9010 directly I get

```
13:19:25,648 INFO  [play] ~ Anonymous Guest ~ MediaCtl.getImgIx(): config {"w":100,"h":65,"origin":"http://localhost:9010","fit":"max"}
```

I see no messages in access.log or error.log with regards to the URL mangling that seems to occur. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: this `/media/{bucket}/{id}/inline/{<.*>config}` route is obviously what your app is listening for. what URL is actually being requested of nginx when the problem happens?

Comment: This would be a URL asked for: http://localhost:8080/media/images/54cbaf853004fd6a7b5026ce/inline/%7B%22w%22%3A150%2C%22h%22%3A125%2C%22origin%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%22%2C%22fit%22%3A%22max%22%7D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx merges slashes from URLs on default
see: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes

You must use: merge_slashes off;